# Failed to install Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: system-installation, acer

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my acer aspire e15. it has intel pentium quad core processor N3540.

Inserted the cd/usb (tried both), boot menu, selected my boot device and then the Ubuntu screen appeared with little dots and was loading forever (I think it froze). Same thing happened when I was using usb.

Tried installing ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, same thing happened.

I've read here that it is possible to install it on my machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: This is probably a video driver issue.

Comment: @pilot6 no black screen, just loads forever.
dots freeze, but I can hear the CD is running, then stops, then goes again, and stops...and so on forever

Comment: It does not matter. Also the disk may be bad.

Comment: no way that there's aything wrong with hardware, because i can install 32 bit ubuntu anytime and everything is working perfectlly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if secure boot is disabled? If it is enabled it will block all software that 'isn't trusted by the system manufacturer'. And it would be likely that a Linux USB is seen as possible harmful software.

Comment: I'll check that, thank you, I'll get back to you when I try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is occurring from BIOS. You need these settings:

```
Secure Boot = <Disabled>           |
UEFI Boot = <Enabled>              |
Boot From Other OS = <Enabled>     |
```